# Problem installing MySql workbench on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: package-management, dependencies, mysql-workbench

I am not able to install mysql workbench on ubuntu 18.04. There is some dependency error. Following are the commands I have tried and their outputs

sudo apt install mysql-workbench

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-workbench : Depends: gdal-abi-2-2-3
                   Depends: libgdal20 (>= 2.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

sudo apt --fix-broken install

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libodbc1 wine-stable
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

sudo apt-get install -f

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

sudo apt-get autoremove

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

These commands gave no output

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep hold`
sudo dpkg --configure -a
apt-mark showhold
```

I also tried using aptitude instead of apt.
I used synaptic package manager. Edit -> Fix Broken Packages. It shows "Successfully fixed dependency problems" at the bottom but problem still not solved.

**Edit:**
I ran this command

```
apt-cache policy mysql-workbench
```

Output

```
mysql-workbench:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 6.3.8+dfsg-1build3
  Version table:
     6.3.8+dfsg-1build3 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
```

**Edit2:** I ran this command

```
apt-cache policy gdal-abi-2-2-3 libgdal20
```

Output

```
gdal-abi-2-2-3:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
libgdal20:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.2.3+dfsg-2
  Version table:
     2.2.3+dfsg-2 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
```

**Edit3** I ran this command

```
sudo apt install libgdal20
```

Output

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgdal20 : Depends: libarmadillo8 but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libhdf5-100 but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libnetcdf13 (>= 4.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

If I try to install any of the dependencies, the same error shows up again telling their dependencies. But isn't apt supposed to install all the dependencies on its own?

**Edit 4:** I ran this command

```
gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Output
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/VncCrpPNHY/

**Edit 5**
I tried installing it with synaptic package manager. On clicking apply after marking mysql-workbench for installation, I got a dialogue box that says

```
Could not apply changes. Fix broken packages first.
```

On going to Edit -> Fix Broken Packages, I get a dialogue box that says

```
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

However if I just open synaptic and do Edit -> fix broken packages without marking MySQL workbench for installation, it says at the bottom "successfully fixed dependency problems".

I ran

```
sudo apt update
```

Output

```
Hit:1 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Hit:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease      
Hit:5 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/18.04/prod bionic InRelease        
Hit:6 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                              
Hit:7 https://debrepo.freedownloadmanager.org bionic InRelease                 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.
```

I ran

```
sudo apt list --upgradable
```

Output

```
Listing... Done
libodbc1/bionic 2.3.7 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.3.4-1.1ubuntu3]
N: There is 1 additional version. Please use the '-a' switch to see it
```

I ran the above command with -a switch

```
sudo apt list --upgradable -a
```

Output

```
Listing... Done
libodbc1/bionic 2.3.7 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.3.4-1.1ubuntu3]
libodbc1/bionic,now 2.3.4-1.1ubuntu3 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 2.3.7]
```

Comment: Ah. I faced similar problems for MariaDB a long time back. I could neither get it to install the dependencies nor could I completely remove it. I suggest a fresh install if you dont have important databases. But maybe, try synaptic first.

Comment: @Jdeep fresh install of what, workbench? But this is the first time I am installing workbench

Comment: @NikhilRathore , I suggest use synaptic to reinstall the broken packages first

Comment: @NikhilRathore Go through this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1081938. It might help you. If you have any doubt, tag my username in your comment such that I'll be notified (like this: @RandomPerson).

Comment: @RandomPerson I have given the link to content of gedit /etc/apt/sources.list. Could you please check what needs to be changed. I uncommented some lines and that didn't make any difference.

Comment: @NikhilRathore Your `sources.list` file looks fine to me. I don't know what exactly is the issue in your computer. I installed Ubuntu 18.04 in a VirtualBox and installed MySQL Workbench successfully. So, there is no issue with the package. Did you try to use Synaptic? If you are not sure how to use Synaptic to install MySQL Workbench, let me know. I will help you. Also, add the output of `sudo apt update` in your question.

Comment: @RandomPerson I tried synaptic and have updated the question. please check edit 5.

Comment: Instant problem: `gdal-abi-2-2-3` - wherever you got the MySQL Workbench installer from is not properly up to date or dependent on things that are not in the Ubuntu repositories at all - `gdal-abi-2-2-3` isn't a valid package and therefore isn't a valid build dependency / install dependency.  Given that `gdal-abi-2-2-3` is in the requirements of the package for installation, and not available on the system, you either (1) have messed up repos, (2) are using an unsynced mirror, or (3) have a bad package.

Comment: Have you tried the version of the mysql workbench from the MySQL repos directly?  Follow the MySQL team's [instructions for setting up their repository](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/#apt-repo-setup), run `sudo apt update` and then do `sudo apt install mysql-workbench-community` - this may be better and supersede whatever problem is going on in the main repos with that package (sometimes using upstream developers' versions works better)

Comment: @ThomasWard I tried as you said in the above comment. sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench still gives same error. sudo apt install mysql-workbench-community says there is no apt package but there is a snap with that name. I have tried that before. It will get installed but due to broken dependency won't work properly.